# SQL Group Duplicate Values and Return as a New Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will query my table, then in the result set for one of the columns return a different, incrementing value, but for duplicates it would have the same value. I'm having trouble finding the right words to explain it but an example should clear it up. Here's an example table:

```
Date           ActionTaken         UserID

2017-12-5      Update              1
2017-12-6      Add                 1
2017-12-6      Delete              1
2017-12-7      Update              1
2017-12-8      Update              1
2017-12-8      Delete              1
```

And when I do my query, I'd like the result to be something like:

```
Date           ActionTaken         UserID

Day 1          Update              1
Day 2          Add                 1
Day 2          Delete              1
Day 3          Update              1
Day 4          Update              1
Day 4          Delete              1
```

`ActionTaken` and `UserID` data are irrelevant, I'd just like to be able to group by values in the `Date` Column, then assign them a new value with an incrementing number, grouping rows with the same `Date` value to have the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by date) as seqnum,
       . . .
from t;
```

This returns a number.  You can, at your leisure, add `date` before the number.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.